# Finding the common things in two images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have to solve a problem in which I need to find the same objects that are located in the same region in the two images.
Subtracting the images is giving very wierd results as the 2images have many other uncommon objects.

Is there any algorithm for this?

Comment: Same exact object? Same view? Same coordinates in the image? Same pixel value inside the object? A few example images? What have you tried?

Comment: Did you google? There are many questions to your question, what are `common things` do you mean similar colors? similar found objects?

Comment: Same objects like lets take an example of some images captured in traffic and a Vehicle has not moved.I want to find the vehicles that didn't move.

Comment: Images are captured from the same point.

Comment: Sample images please.

Comment: you could use simple frame differencing for that specific example.

Answer (score 0):

I've done frame differencing and few bitwise AND operations to extract the stationary object in the foreground. Need to test this on Generalised cases. Once it is done, I will post the methodology in detail.